# Karate UI: driver.location method induces Error: path: $, actual: null

Tags: karate

I am trying to use method driver.location, but as a result I got the error : path: $, actual: null

My code:
Feature: browser automation
  Background:
   * configure driver = { type: 'chromedriver', showDriverLog: true }

Scenario: try to login to github
  and then do a google search

Given driver 'https://github.com/login'
  Then match driver.location == 'https://github.com/login'

EROR: path: $, actual: null,

How to deal with this behavior?

Comment: Please format your question properly :)

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you are on the latest RC version 0.9.5.RC4, and we did rename `location` to `url`: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#driverurl

Or use `waitForUrl()` which is better: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#waitforurl

```
Given driver 'https://github.com/login'
Then waitForUrl('https://github.com/login')
```

Note that there is a ZIP release (including a demo web-browser-test) which can be simpler to use here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release

Comment: It is very quick answer! Thank you!